# Model not being pushed into collection of backbonejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knv29qgb/)

I'm trying to create a message client using [this tutorial](http://codebyexample.info/2012/04/05/backbone-in-baby-steps-part-2/) at this point, the view is supposed to be updated when a new message is typed into the field and the add button is clicked.
For some reason the "addMessage" Event is failing to add a new model to the collection.

```js
var messagesjson = [
  { 
    id: 3,
    message: "This is the message",
    sender: "gabriel",
    receiver: "gabriel",
    has_been_read: false,
    has_been_reported: false,
    created_at: "2014-10-23T19:55:20+0200",
    is_friend: false
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    message: "I'm loving this ",
    sender: "gabriel",
    receiver: "gabriel",
    has_been_read: true,
    has_been_reported: false,
    created_at: "2014-10-23T20:02:34+0200",
    is_friend: false
  }];

var MessageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:
  {
    id: 3,
    message: "This is the message",
    sender: "gabriel",
    receiver: "gabriel",
    has_been_read: false,
    has_been_reported: false,
    created_at: "2014-10-23T19:55:20+0200",
    is_friend: false
  }
});

var MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "div",
  className: "listview",
  template: $('#messageTemplate').html(),
  render: function()
  {
    var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
    console.log(this.model);
    this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});

var MessageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MessageModel
});

var MessageCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#messages'),
  initialize: function()
  {
    this.collection = new MessageCollection(messagesjson);
    this.render();
    this.collection.on("add", this.renderMessage, this);
  },
  render: function()
  {
    var that = this;
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
      that.renderMessage(item);
    },this);
  },
  events:{
    "click #add":"addMessage"
  },
  renderMessage: function(item)
  {
    var messageview = new MessageView({
      model: item
    });

    this.$el.append(messageview.render().el);
  },
  addMessage: function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = {};

    $("#addMessage").children("input").each(function (i, el) {
      formData[el.id] = $(el).val();
    });

    messagesjson.push(formData);
    this.collection.add(new MessageModel(formData));

    console.log(messagesjson);
  }
});

var messagecollectionview = new MessageCollectionView();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div id="messages">  
  <form id="addMessage" action="#">
    <div>
      <label for="messageText">Message: </label>
      <input id="messageText" type="text" />
      <button id="add">Add</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="messageTemplate">
  <a href="#" class="list autoWidth <% if(has_been_read) { %> selected <% } %>">
    <div class="list-content">
      <img src="//www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=20774792" class="icon">
      <div class="data">
      <span class="item-title-secondary fg-gray"><b><%= sender %></b></span>
    </div>
    <span class="tertiary-text">
      <%= message %>
    </span>
    </div>
  </a>
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle of your problem?

Comment: just added the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the id as 3 for all new models as your defaults hash contains `id: 3`. The collection thinks it is the same model as it already has a model with that id.

So first you need to change your defaults with `id:null`:

```
var MessageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        id: null,
        message: "This is the message",
        sender: "gabriel",
        receiver: "gabriel",
        has_been_read: false,
        has_been_reported: false,
        created_at: "2014-10-23T19:55:20+0200",
        is_friend: false
    }
});
```

Then you need to fix the code getting the formData. First of all you are using [jQuery `children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method which only looks at immediate childrens. That means you will never get the inputs inside the form as there is an intermediate div. You could use `find`.

Secondly, you need to make sure that formData has a property named `message` so it can override the default `message: "This is the message"`. I would add a name attribute `message` to the input element and use it like `formData[el.name] = $(el).val();`. (You could later use one of the jquery `serializeObject` plugins to automatically serialize all input elements this way).

So the `addMessage` would look like this:

```
addMessage: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = {};

    $("#addMessage").find("input").each(function (i, el) {
        formData[el.name] = $(el).val();
    });                

    messagesjson.push(formData);
    this.collection.add(new MessageModel(formData));
}
```

You can try it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eeu3dk03/)

Comment: God, you're the best I've been struggling with this for hours